# Is this change to Vim's syntax coloring file for sed good or disrupting?

Tags: vim, sed, syntax-highlighting

### Summary

- I'm not asking your opinion about the proposed change being good, bad, amazing, or what.
- I'm just asking your help to answer this question: *does the change I propose for the syntax coloring of the comments **break** the syntax coloring of something else (keywords, strings, syntax errors, ...)?*
- The question above is **not** opinion based, as my change either does break something or it doesn't. That's it.

### Original question

I have created the [issue #5876](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5876) on Vim's GitHub page to propose a change to `vim/runtime/syntax/sed.vim`, but it has not received much attention, so I'm considering creating a PR for the change.

In fact, I created an issue instead of a PR because I'm not totally confident the change is not disruptive, hence this question.

The issue is with line 20:

```
syn match sedComment    "^\s*#.*$"
```

because of which only "full line" comments are colored as comments. Using trailing comments following a command (allowed by GNU sed, for instance), stimulates some red background coloring (since it's considered an error by the syntax coloring logic, I guess).

I think it would be reasonable to relax this definition of comments to permit GNU sed-style comments, for the simple reason that the rule is less restrictive.

In this respect, I have noticed that changing that line to

```
syn match sedComment    "\s*#.*$"
```

i.e. just removing the anchor `^`, seems to be enough. I have also tried testing it by putting some `#` in search and replace strings in a sed script, and it seems fine.

However I don't feel confident with Vim syntax coloring files, so I would like to be sure that regex, as I edited it, is not causing false positives.

To demonstrate why I'm not confident about it, take this single-line `sed` script

```
s/aaa/bbb/#ccc
```

here `#` is not colored as a comment, and `ccc`'s background is red (like an error?), whereas, just adding a space, give the correct coloring:

```
s/aaa/bbb/ #ccc
```

Therefore I think that my edit works (or seems to work) because of precedence rules between the several syntax coloring directives (with respect to this specific example with `s/aaa/bbb/#ccc`, I think that `#` just after the closing delimiter of the `s` command has a meaning in the language, but I don't know; the GNU Sed `man` page doesn't say anything about it).

### Edit

Another example suggested in the comments is the following, the syntax coloring of which is **not** broken by the proposed change

```
s/#if !defined(\([^)]*)/#ifndef \1/ # with or without this comment is fine
```

Comment: `\s*#.*$` is basically the same as `\s*#.*`, but please bear in mind it can match 0+ whitespaces, `#` and the rest of the line at any position on a line. E.g. it will match `#abc"; # SOME COMMENT` in `text="This is a string #abc"; # SOME COMMENT`

Comment: Yes, @WiktorStribiżew, I know what that regex matches, but the syntax file does not seem to give it a chance. As in, if I put `#` somewhere in a sed script, it is not colored like a comment, even if `\s*#.*$` would match, I write _would_ because I'm pretty sure it is never applied to it, maybe because some other syntax rule takes the precedence. This is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I've tried to clarify why I'm asking this question and what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't understand why this has been closed as _opinion-based_. There's no opinion. The change I proposed is either fine or it breaks something, and I'm asking help for understanding which one is the case. That's it. If, instead, someone thinks that this is off topic because I should post it on [Vi and Vim Beta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), that's another story.

Comment: What does your suggestion do with `s/#if !defined(\([^)]*)/#ifndef \1/`?  I think that's probably a problem — there's no comment in that code, but your change would treat it like a comment, would it not?  Also, all the world does not use GNU `sed`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, my proposed change does not treat any of those two `#` as comments. Concerning the last sentence, my proposed change would not impact the syntax of existing non-GNU `sed` script files.

Comment: OK, if you say so.  I've not studied what's involved in the syntax highlighting code in vim.  I'm not sure how your `sed` syntax highlighter knows whether it's highlighting GNU or some other species of `sed` code.  Anyway, I have no objection to it if your change don't mishandle such constructs, or variants such as `s#/proxy/#/haproxy/#`, etc.  But I'm no authority on the subject of syntax highlighting — as you can tell.

Comment: If it's not POSIX compatible (I suspect not as it fails in FreeBSD ) then it's not unfortunately not great. You can customize your custom syntax highlighting I believe. FWIW in `sh`  syntax you can specify `posix`  to allow `$()`, so customization is doable

Answer (score 1):

### My research

I have eventually found some time to study `:h E410` and now I have an answer.

From there I read that

> ```
> 1. Keyword
>     [...] It will only match with a complete word [...]
> 2. Match
>     This is a match with a single regexp pattern.
> 3. Region
>     This starts at a match of the "start" regexp pattern and ends with a match with the
>     "end" regexp pattern.  Any other text can appear in between.  A "skip" regexp
>     pattern can be used to avoid matching the "end" pattern.
> ```

Since the line I'm going to change uses the syntax 2.,

- point 1. is not relevant,
- point 3. **is** relevant, as in general there can be an overlap between the what `syn match` and `syn region` match.

(By the way, I verified that `syn region` uses a lazy regex, probably `\_.\{-}` looking at some examples afterwards, to match stuff between the `start` and `end` regexp patterns.)

Then from `:h :syn-priority`

> ```
> An item that starts in an earlier position has priority over items that start in later positions.
> ```

### The answer

Therefore, changing

```
syn match sedComment    "^\s*#.*$"
```

to

```
syn match sedComment    "\s*#.*$"
```

should not *introduce* any syntax error, the reason being that if a text matching the above regex is not actually a comment (as is the case for e.g. the command `s/#/hash/`), then it must be **preceded** by some non-comment syntax which will be matched by other `syn match`/`syn region` groups. Since this match starts before where the group `sedComment` starts to match, the former has precedence on the latter.

In conclusion, unless something is broken with `sed.vim` already, the proposed change will not result in a wrong syntax coloring.

### Further observations

Actually, there is already something wrong in `sed.vim`, and my proposed edit does not solve it (I should edit some other line in `sed.vim` to fix it, but I'm a bit lazy now).

For instance, in the following line, which is illegal because `a` is not a valid flag, `a` does not get the `Error` coloring.

```
s/x/y/a
```

My proposed edit does not solve this bug.

For the same reason, since some other syntax rule is eating 1 character after the third delimiter in the substitution command, the GNU-`sed`-valid comment in the following command is incorrectly colored

```
s/x/y/#hello
#     │└───┴─── colored as Error
#     └─ not colored
```

The coloring would be wrong even for an old version of `sed` which does not allow trailing comments, as the `Error` coloring should include the `#` too.
My proposed edit does not solve this bug either.

### One more observation

The change I propose causes single-letter commands to be highlighted as `Error` if they are followed by a comment

```
p # this is a comment
│ └─────────────────┴─── colored as Comment (ok)
└────── colored as Error (bad)
```

This again, is not a worsening, as the current `sed.vim` colors almost the whole line above as an `Error`.

Comment: Did you ever open a PR for this? I see [Issue #5876](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5876) is closed with no solution, and I'm having the same problem in current vim (9.0.700). I opened [PR #11353](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/11353) and commented on the issue.

Comment: I opened the issue you linked.

Comment: Thanks for all your research. I would appreciate your take on my fix.

Comment: @Jacktose you mean accepting it? I can't, sorry 

Comment: No, I just mean checking it out. Does it look to you like it'll fix your issue? Do you see any problems?

Comment: @Jacktose, can't do right now. I'll try to do it after work.

Comment: Bram has accepted it (no patch published yet), and [the file has a new maintainer](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/11353#issuecomment-1279081088). 

Comment: Oh, very good then!